# SSH Alias prompts passcode authentication but direct SSH works

Tags: bash, ssh, security

I'm trying to SSH into a server on which I have sshd running (let's call it me@server).  I set up ssh keys by using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` to create the key and then I ran `cat ~/.rsa/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@server 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'`.  Now when I run `ssh user@server` I connect to the server no problem.  But when I use the alias `ssh server` I am prompted for my key's password (which doesn't ahve a password) and eventually enter `user@server`'s password (which is what I was trying to avoid in the first place.

Here's my `.ssh/config` on my local machine:

```
Host server
    HostName my_ip
    User user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

I checked all the file/directory permissions on both the local and remote machine, and they all appeared to be correct.  Anyone have any idea what's going on?

**UPDATE**

So I figured that since the login worked without the `-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` option I might as well try the host without the `IndentityFile ~/.rsa/id_rsa.pub` So I took that line out of the config file and it all worked.  i ahve no clue why.  Anyone care to explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

You're specifying the public key here. You should specify the private key instead. The private key probably named `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

`~/.ssh/id_rsa` happens to be one of the default key file names which `ssh` looks for. When you removed the erroneous keyfile specification from your command, `ssh` probably fell back to looking for its default keys, and used `id_rsa` for the session.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure it's asking for your key file's password and not the remote server password?

Second, SSH has an incredibly verbose debug mode if you specify command line options: -v -v -v

You can do the same on the server: -d -d -d

That should tell you exactly what's happening on both sides and explain any bizarre behavior.

If I had to guess, I suspect the SSH client is resolving a different private key and then forcing a prompt for some reason, but the debug output is the way to find out.

If I have 4 different private keys, I'll list them all as IdentityFile entries.  That should resolve this problem - if it's indeed substituting an unexpected key.